# Multiple if/then statements with an array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

Short version: I'm looking to create multiple conditions in an if/then statement which all need to be met. One of those conditions is an array.
Problem: It's ignoring my final condition/array.

Long story: I run a game with a strange calendar system, seen : http://www.beqanna.com/forum/bqcalendar.php. I'm trying to have something on the left side where it says "current season" spit out the current season. I'm having a lot of problems with it understanding the "month".

```html
$d = date('d');
$m = date('m');
$season = '';

If ($d > '1' && $d < '15' && ($m == '01' or '03' or '05' or '07' or '09' or '11')) {
    $season = 'Winter';
} If ($d > '16' && $d < '18' && ($m == '01' or '03' or '05' or '07' or '09' or '11')) {
    $season = 'Spring';
} If ($d > '19' && $d < '23' && ($m == '01' or '03' or '05' or '07' or '09' or '11')) {
    $season = 'Spring, Birthing';
} If ($d > '24' && $d < '31' && ($m == '01' or '03' or '05' or '07' or '09' or '11')) {
    $season = 'Spring';
} If ($d > '1' && $d < '15' && ($m == '02' or '04' or '06' or '08' or '10' or '12')) {
    $season = 'Summer';
} If ($d > '16' && $d < '18' && ($m == '02' or '04' or '06' or '08' or '10' or '12')) {
    $season = 'Autumn';
} If ($d > '19' && $d < '23' && ($m == '02' or '04' or '06' or '08' or '10' or '12')) {
    $season = 'Autumn, Breeding';
} If ($d > '24' && $d < '31' && ($m == '02' or '04' or '06' or '08' or '10' or '12')) {
    $season = 'Autumn';
}
```

Other things I've tried -
$m == array (01,03,05,07,09)
$m == (%2) - for the even number months
I've tried moving my ' around the entire thing, adding and subtracting ( ). My final conclusion is that - for whatever reason - it isn't "listening" to the month. Like right now it should say "winter" but it keeps reading "Summer," which is the 1-15 date (correct) but wrong month.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure about `($m == '01' or '03' or '05' or '07' or '09' or '11')`?

Comment: That's my most recent attempt and it's currently spitting out "summer" even though it should say "winter".

Comment: You also can use `in_array($m, array('01', '03',...))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've forgot the `else` statement.

And you currently check if the date is **above** `1` **and** **under** `15`. So your routine won't work for dates like `15, 16, 18, 19, 23, 24, 31`.

You have to change the operator `>` to `>=`, so you will check if the date is **above OR equal** to the if.

For example your old code:

```
if ($d > 1 && ....)
```

If your date is 1, it **won't** go into this if.

New code:

```
if ($d >= 1 && ....)
```

If your date is 1, it **will** go into this if.

Here the complete routine:

```
$d = date('d');
$m = date('m');
$season = '';

$winterMonths = array(1,3,5,7,9,11);
$summerMonths = array(2,4,6,8,10,12);

if ($d >= 1 && $d <= 15 && in_array($m, $winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Winter';
} else if ($d >= 16 && $d <= 18 && in_array($m, $winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Spring';
} else if ($d >= 19 && $d <= 23 && in_array($m, $winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Spring, Birthing';
} else if ($d >= 24 && $d <= 31 && in_array($m, $winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Spring';
} else if ($d >= 1 && $d <= 15 && in_array($m, $summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Summer';
} else if ($d >= 16 && $d <= 18 && in_array($m, $summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Autumn';
} else if ($d >= 19 && $d <= 23 && in_array($m, $summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Autumn, Breeding';
} else if ($d >= 24 && $d <= 31 && in_array($m, $summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Autumn';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @CourtneyDeer I updated my solution. You need to `()` the month dates too.

If this helps you, please remember to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Initially it appeared to work, but now that it's September 16th it doesn't display anything. Back to square one :(

Comment: @CourtneyDeer I updated my answer again. Please check if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized that last night as well, and this seems to have done the trick. However, I didn't use the $wintermonths because it crashes the entire code. I've learned MyBB is VERY finnicky. I appreciate you taking another look!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your first expression will always return true.

```
&& ($m == '01' or '03' or '05' or '07' or '09' or '11') 
// $m == 1 OR tru or true... and becomes false or true or true
```

You could use `in_array`.

Here is the code you need.

```
<?php
$d = (int)date('d');
$m = (int)date('m');
$season = '';

//echo $d . ' ' . $m . PHP_EOL;

$winterMonths = [1,3,5,7,9,11];
$summerMonths = [2,4,6,8,10,12];

If ($d > 1 && $d < 15 && in_array($m,$winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Winter';
} else if ($d > 16 && $d < 18 && in_array($m,$winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Spring';
} else if ($d > 19 && $d < 23 && in_array($m,$winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Spring, Birthing';
} else if ($d > 24 && $d < 31 && in_array($m,$winterMonths)) {
    $season = 'Spring';
} else if ($d > 1 && $d < 15 && in_array($m,$summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Summer';
} else if ($d > 16 && $d < 18 && in_array($m,$summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Autumn';
} else if ($d > 19 && $d < 23 && in_array($m,$summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Autumn, Breeding';
} else if ($d > 24 && $d < 31 && in_array($m,$summerMonths)) {
    $season = 'Autumn';
}

echo $season;
```

Hope it helps.